# Save a nested many-to-many relationship and it's members in django rest framework

Tags: django, nested, many-to-many, django-rest-framework, relationship

How can I save a nested many-to-many relationship in Django Rest Framework while creating it's members at the same time? My data structure looks like that (very simplified example):

```
base = {
  relations: [
     {from: "member 1", to: "member 2"},
     {from: "member 2", to: "member 3"},
  ]
  members: [
    {name: "member 1"},
    {name: "member 2"},
    {name: "member 3"},
  ]
}
```

In Django:

```
class Base(models.Model):
  pass

class Member(models.Model):
  base = models.ForeignKey(Base, related_name='members')
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Relation(models.Model):
  base = models.ForeignKey(Base, related_name='relations')
  from = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='froms')
  to = models.ForeignKey(Member, related_name='tos')
```

The serializers:

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('name', )

class RelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    from = MemberSerializer()
    to = MemberSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('from', 'to')

class BaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    members = MemberSerializer(many=True)
    relations = RelationSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ('from', 'to')
        depth = 3
```

The problem here is that I cannot save the relations because the member's primary key is not yet available before saving the members, so I dont know how to put that into relation. The only possible solution I theoretically could come up with is somehow savig the "members" subset of that data structure first and then have some logic to replace the string ("member 1", etc) with the correct primary key before saving to db. Also I cannot split this request into two separate requests.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

When saving manyToMany usually you should use models.ManyToManyField instead of models.ForgeinKey

regarding your question you can add something like this to your serializer

```
class RelationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
members = MemberSerializer(many=True)
relations = RelationSerializer(many=True)

def create(self, validated_data):

    # save relation
    relation= Relation(from=validated_data['from'],to==validated_data['to']...)
    relation.save()
    #your primary key will be created

    # add the relation
    items =validated_data['relation']
    # get the exact member like member=Member.objects.get(name=item['name'])
    # add the link


    return relation
```